# How do I use a geospatial query in the MongoDB C#?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb-query, geospatial

How can I run geo queries using C#

Something as simple as this:

```
db.restaurants.find({ location:
       { $geoWithin:
          { $centerSphere: [ [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ], 5 / 3963.2 ] } } })
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: can you please tell us if the executed the code in your question and if yes what is the error you are getting or what is not working exactly

Comment: No,
I just do not know how to write geographic queries in the C# code :(

Comment: Since SO is not a coding service the best way it to give it a go show the effort you have done which will encourage others to help you once you get stuck

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986155/how-do-i-use-a-geospatial-query-in-the-2-1-mongodb-c-sharp-driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got along,
Here's how:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.GeoWithinCenterSphere("location", -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ,5 / 3963.2);

var results =  collection.Find(filter).toList();
```

Thanks